# Rancher 2.x - HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: rancher

I installed Rancher 2.4.4 using the [docs](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/k8s-install/helm-rancher/) and everything is working. I can access the server using https using my custom domain **rancher.mydomain.com**.

I created an Ingress using **test.mydomain.com** to access a service. I am using self-signed certificate to test https://test.mydomain.com access and it is working. But I can access the same service using http. How can I make a redirect or avoid access to my cluster using http? This is the ingress with sensitive information changed:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/creatorId: user-tk7hh
    field.cattle.io/ingressState: '{"dW5pbWVk":"p-pfqlz:test","abc":"deployment:test:httpbin","abc==":"deployment:test:httpbin"}'
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"addresses":["1.2.3.4"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"unimed:ingress-5d3e64b41895cfc7d3d354d63a7d83d0","ingressName":"test:test","hostname":"test.mydomain.com","path":"/status","allNodes":false},{"addresses":["1.2.3.4"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"test:ingress-9922b5a9032d962093476e63c4335d80","ingressName":"test:test","hostname":"test.mydomain.com","path":"/delay","allNodes":false}]'
  creationTimestamp: "2020-06-05T23:28:23Z"
  generation: 11
  labels:
    cattle.io/creator: norman
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: traefik
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-06-05T23:28:23Z"
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/creatorId: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/ingressState: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:cattle.io/creator: {}
      f:spec:
        f:rules: {}
        f:tls: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-06-08T19:22:11Z"
  name: unimed
  namespace: unimed
  resourceVersion: "998963"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/test/ingresses/test
  uid: b138da9d-9ca8-4a23-a9b9-3ae1e400177d
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ingress-5d3e64b41895cfc7d3d354d63a7d83d0
          servicePort: 80
        path: /status
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: ingress-9922b5a9032d962093476e63c4335d80
          servicePort: 80
        path: /delay
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.mydomain.com
    secretName: test
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Could you share the Ingress config? Also, how did you install Rancher?

Comment: I edited the question with the informations.

Comment: I don't have a v2.4.4 setup handy, but I tried this on v2.3.5 and I see a redirect from Nginx ingress controller when I try to access using HTTP. How are you accessing the service using HTTP? And from where are you trying it out?

Comment: I am using Firefox, external to the server. I can access the workload using HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: I see a reference of "traefik" in your manifest, may be there is some setting in there?

Comment: Good hint. I discovered the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Rancher 2.4.4 uses Traefik as a load balancer. We need to put this annotation to make a redirect

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-entry-point: https
```

It is possible to do this in the Ingress using the interface.

[image]